# MATLAB free memory without clear command

Tags: matlab, memory-management, shared, parfor

I need to free memory with Matlab without clear command (I'm inside a parfor loop of parallel toolbox and I can't call clear); I read that,for example, instead of

```
clear v
```

I can set

```
v=[]
```

the question is: with '= []' I deallocate the memory of 'v' or just set v to an empty value and the previous memory is still allocated and then unusable? 
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read correctly.  Here's a demonstration:

My computer's memory right now (after clearing the workspace, but with some leftovers and plots in place):

```
>> memory
Maximum possible array:            54699 MB (5.736e+10 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:            54699 MB (5.736e+10 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:             1003 MB (1.052e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):            32695 MB (3.428e+10 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

Allocate a billion element array and check memory again:

```
>> x = rand(1e6,1e3);
>> memory
Maximum possible array:            46934 MB (4.921e+10 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:            46934 MB (4.921e+10 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:             8690 MB (9.113e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):            32695 MB (3.428e+10 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

Set the variable to [].  Most memory is again available (note a small loss):

```
>> x = [];
>> memory
Maximum possible array:            54578 MB (5.723e+10 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:            54578 MB (5.723e+10 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:             1061 MB (1.113e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):            32695 MB (3.428e+10 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

Comment: @ Pursuit Your method is OK just for x with large size.When the size of x is small,such as x=1.Your method could not work.

Comment: A variable `v` will still exist, requiring a very small amount of memory (listed as 0, but some overhead must exist).  If the previous value of `v` required a lot of memory (the original question) then could be a big advantage.  If the previous value of `v` required 8 bytes (e.g. `v=1`) then there is really no reason to do this.  Also no reason to run `clear v`.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to find the answer with the help of function 'whos'.For example,I create a variable v=1.

```
v=1;
```

type 'whos',we could find all variables in memory:

```
whos;
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  v         1x1                 8  double
```

we could find the variable v in memory.
Then I try to 'delete' v:

```
v=[];
```

type 'whos' to check whether it is delete or not:

```
 whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  v         0x0                 0  double
```

It is very clear that using 'v=[];' could not delete a variable in memory,it's just create an empty variable instead.

```
clear;
whos;
```

Nothing is printed,there is no variable in memory.